# Easiest & fastest way to export a Python program to run on another computer?

Tags: python, wxpython, export, pydev

My friend does not have Python or the libraries needed installed on his machine to run a program I have written.  Is there a simple way to export my project (currently sitting in pydev on my x64 Windows 7 machine) so that he could run it on his machine? (He has OSX, but he could find Unix or Windows if needed.)  My program uses several modules, and depends on networkx, wx, and matplotlib.

Feel free to move this to programming if overflow isn't appropriate.

Thanks!

Comment: Just bundle all 3rd party dependencies locally to the project.

Comment: @Jakob care to explain what the best way to do so is?

Comment: just keep your dependancies local to your script. E.g. in the same path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) (Windows), [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) (should work on any platform that Python itself works on) or [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html) (Mac OS X).

Answer (score 2):

OS X actually already has python installed, albeit a somewhat old version.  On OS X, a great solution to getting newer python [Mac Ports](http://www.macports.org/) package manager.

On Windows, python has an installer, and many of the most popular modules also have installers that respect the installed python.  Alternatively, you can use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to install X-Windows versions of same.

On unix like platforms, well, you're already good to go.  Python is preinstalled on just about every distro, and the package manager will have all of the popular modules ready to install, too.